# How to make liquid boil

Tags: animation, physics

Super simple premise, but can't figure it out. How do I make a spitting boil, like lava or another thicker liquid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you expand on this question - perhaps by providing examples of the effect you're looking for. For example, is it the bubbles rising or breaking the surface or "globs" being ejected from the surface, etc. I'm sure there are many ways of achieving parts of this depending on the desired result or interpretation of the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Create Plane.
Create icosphere.
Select Plane, go to properties tab, particles:

1. Create a new particle system.
2. Go to render tab on particles properties and select object. Use the
   picker and select the icosphere.
3. You will see particles being emitted downwards.
4. Go to world tab, scroll down to gravity tab. Mark it off.
5. Play animation. Bubbles start coming up. Great!
6. Go to the property tab-particles and choose emit number: use 25.
7. Next change life: set life 6 frames.
8. Next change emission from faces. Choose Random.
9. Now play with life parameters RANDOM to give particles a random
   timing of death between 0 and 6 frames.
10. After you set that, you can add a turbulence force field. leave as
     default. Watch them bubbles.

Now: Any changes you do to the icosphere will reflect on the bubbles.

Create a sphere move it to intersect half of your icosphere. Select icosphere and use a boolean modifier. Select the sphere as boolean operation set to SUBSTRACT.

Play particle sim, you'll see your bubbles have a hole.

Now, animate the boolean sphere up and down quick enough in the timeline (you can press play and move it with <kbd>G</kbd>) and some will come complete and othera with just half bubble.

If you animate this consistently you'll get desired BASE effect.

Thank you for your consideration to vote this as answer by ticking the check mark at the left side.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Seems it can work, but a big lack of illustrations.